Completeness of bidirectional type checking by inversion
I'm currently reading through the completeness proof of the paper "Complete and Easy Bidirectional Typechecking for Higher-Rank Polymorphism" by Dunfield et al.
In the second case Dunfield et al. argue by inversion that the premise of the rule in question also holds and then continue by induction hypothesis. In all other case they do not argue by inversion but directly apply the hypothesis to the premise. I don't understand why the inversion step is needed in the second case and we cannot argument directly by i.h.?

I don't know what they mean by "inversion" exactly but there is nothing fundamentally different about that case, so probably just a stylistic inconsistency.

My understanding of inversion is that the premises are true iff the conclusion is true. But when second case happens, we already assume that the premises hold don't we? So no need to argument by inversion in my understanding.

That is correct.
